# Chase for/after x

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

> He played basketball alone in the park to chase after new friendship.
>
> He played basketball alone in the park to chase for new friendship.

None of them sound particularly correct, but I can't think of a better way to phrase this.

Comment: chase after friendship is not great here. To find new friendships.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this, in my opinion.

Firstly, the phrasal verb `chase after` is usually used in **literal** situations where someone is actually pursuing someone else.

> I **chased after** the pickpocket who stole my wallet.
> The dog **chased after** the cat but couldn't catch it.

If you want to use 'chase' figuratively, you can use `chase + Noun`. For example:

> We are always **chasing** happiness but we never seem to achieve it.
> She spent her life **chasing** fame and fortune.
> That guy only cares about **chasing** women.   (approaching women for romantic purposes)

This usage often has a negative connotation. The implication is that the 'chasing' is too hurried or hasty, or that the process involved might be questionable.

Finally, 'chasing friendship' sounds a little unnatural because, as mentioned, `chasing + Noun` tends to be used to question the validity of the pursuit. There is nothing questionable about wanting to make friends, so it sounds a little strange (to me). I would use a different phrase, such as:

> He played basketball alone in the park, **hoping to find friendship**.
> He played basketball alone in the park, **hoping to make new friends**.